# Update the Price of an item when adding to the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, custom-product-type, custom-prices, gift-card

So here's my project. 
Make our giftcard integration purchasable.

Basically I need to get an "Enter Custom Amount" input field to update the price of the item. 
What I have been told by our architect is that I should Update the `MyCompany_GiftCard_Model_Product_Type_GiftCard` class to extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract`

then override the _prepareProduct Method to use the value from the custom amount if defined. So. I made this method:

```
protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode) {
    $result = parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
    $oRide = $buyRequest->getOverrideAmount();
    $stn_amt = $buyRequest->getAmount();
    $productGiftCard = $buyRequest->getGiftCard();

    if(isset($oRide) && ($oRide != '') && ($oRide != 0) && ($oRide != null)){
        $result[0]->addCustomOption('giftcard_amount', $oRide);
    }else{
        $result[0]->addCustomOption('giftcard_amount', $amount);
    }

    if (!empty($productGiftCard)) {
        return $result;
    } 
    return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please specify the required options of product.');
}
```

Then I was told to update the `getFinalPrice()` method to accept the new value from `MyCompany_GiftCard_Model_Product_Type_GiftCard_Price`

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty = null, $product)
{
    $finalPrice = parent::getFinalPrice($qty, $product);
    $amount = $product->getCustomOption('giftcard_amount'); // its an object or false
    if($amount) {
        $finalPrice = $qty * $amount->getValue();
    }
    // echo '<br>finalPrice: '.$finalPrice;
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    // echo $product->getData('final_price');
    // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract

    return max(0, $product->getData('final_price'));
}
```

Here's the thing. 
If you do: echo $product->getData('final_price')); 
It totally equals the price I want to be! If the custom amount is set, final_price == custom amount!

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong and why the GetFinalPrice is not the price for the item in checkout?

(I'm rather new to Magento, 3 months-ish, but our architect was quite adamant that updating the getFinalPrice() method directly update the price in the cart! He's unavailable right now, and I have a deadline.

Comment: Kudos for a well written question. You should add that your issue is that in cart the price of the item is not your custom amount (assuming I understood you correctly). You need to set that price for the quote - when the item is added to cart

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that getFinalPrice is the correct place, however I think you may be missing some calls to 'set it' correctly.

Have a look at this github file:

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/GiftPromo/blob/master/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/GiftPromo/Model/Product/Type/Gift/Simple/Price.php

This is from a GiftPromo module I wrote aeons ago. It basically does teh same thing - The product (proper product in catalog, with price) can be gifted (no new sku is used, the actual catalog product, and SKU , is gifted, BUT the price is adapted to what i set in admin for that product gifting rule)

In my code you will see I get the price for the item, from a value stored in `info_buyRequest` (`$giftedPrice = $buyRequest->getGiftedPrice()`;) - I literally set the 'updated price' to the `info_BuyRequest` upon add-to-cart, and then set the finalPrice, based on that value, in the given routine. (this is all handled in lines 23-46, with teh value resulting in `$giftedPrice`

Now, if you check my code, there are a couple of things I do, that you don't (I have not used/worked with this moule in years, so I don't recall 100% what they all do)

`$finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);`

`$product->setCalculatedFinalPrice($finalPrice);`

I highly suspect that last one is what you are misisng.

I hope this helps in some way.

PS: You will find a Price.php class for all product types in the parent folder:

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/GiftPromo/tree/master/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/GiftPromo/Model/Product/Type/Gift

Comment: This is a pretty great answer. Thanks! I actually figured out the issue. There was an observer that changing the price right before it updated the cart price! Somehow I missed it. Again, I am new to Magento, so I don't always pick up on everything. It seems that the case where adding a customOption was already anticipated and had a 'code' already set up in the observer. But I will indeed go through your module and have a look around. Thank you @ProxiBlue +1
I will also post a more explicit explanation shortly with code examples.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting frustrated, so I just did a general search of the code for `['amount']` and this is what I found inside of
**app/code/local/Company/Giftcard/Model/Observer.php:**

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // set custom price for the quote item
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    if ($product->isGiftCard()) {
        if ($customPrice = $product->getData('custom_option')) {
            $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
        }

        // save reorder data
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();

        if (!$action) {
            return;
        }

        if ($customWishListPrice = $item->getOptionByCode('giftcard_amount')) {
            $item->setCustomPrice($customWishListPrice->getValue());
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customWishListPrice->getValue());
        }
        if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_reorder') {
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $options = $item->getBuyRequest()->getGiftCard();
            parse_str($options, $optionsArray);
            if (count($optionsArray)) {
                $item->setPrice($optionsArray['amount']);
                unset($optionsArray['amount']);
                $additionalOptions = array();
                foreach ($optionsArray as $optionCode => $value) {
                    $additionalOptions[] = array(
                        'label' => $optionCode,
                        'value' => $value,
                    );
                }
                $item->addOption(array(
                    'code' => 'additional_options',
                    'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part that was causing me the headache was

```
if ($customPrice = $product->getData('custom_option')) {
    $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
}
```

So I changed it to

```
if ($customPrice = $product->getData('giftcard_amount')) {
    $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
}
```

and it worked! 
There were also some other supporting observer methods that I had to change the custom_amount to giftcard_amount. But this example is enough to support my point. This module was already coded to accept a custom_amount for the giftcard, but I didn't know it!

I thought I did everything right but somehow 'magic gremlins' were getting ahold of my request and swapping around the amounts and submitting them to the cart. But it was just an observer I hadn't noticed!